# How to draw rectangle around tiled object in a MATLAB plot?

Tags: matlab, plot, tile

I created a tiledlayout(4,3)-object and I want to emphasize the 8th tile by a surrounding line or changing the backgroundcolor (not of the graph itself, but just the greyspace behind the graph, labels, axes etc.).

I could not find anything that changes the backgroundcolor of just one tile, so I tried to draw a rectangle around the tile and color it. 
I executed the code below and expected to get a red line around the OuterPosition- or the TightInset-position, but nothing happened. The code created the tiles without any error-codes and there was no red rectangle around the 8th tile.

Can anyone tell me how to color the background of a tile or get a rectangle around it?

Thank you very much!

```
ax = nexttile(8)
lines_around_tile = get(ax, 'OuterPosition'); %'TightInset')
rectangle('Position', lines_around_tile, 'EdgeColor', 'r', 'LineWidth',10)
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this result.

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqpvZ.jpg)

To draw a rectangle, run the code and in matlab figure (with all the tiles) go to view -> Plot Edit Toolbar. It generates a toolbar where you can find lines, rectangles, circles...

Then insert your rectangle, right click on it, Property Inspector. In this window you can change the facecolor, linecolor, linewidth...

Comment: Thank you very much, this helps! But is there a way to do this within the code? Editing afterwards can get messy, if there are multiple plots...